# How to display the list of guests from getGuestList()?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This code is supposed to display the guest list for meetings in a Google Sheet. However, getGuestList() returns an array and it appears I cannot get the list of guests in a cell.

Below is a snippet of the code I'm working with.

```
cell = sheet.getRange(row, 7);
var guestArrayItem = events[i].getGuestList();
var guestDetails = guestArrayItem[i].getName();

guestArrayItem.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
  cell.setValue(guestDetails);
})
```

**All I'm trying to do is display the guest names in the cell.**

A couple notes.

1. I know that in it's current form, it will constantly overwrite itself with the next iteration of a users name. I am trying to get it to display any name at all at the moment...
2. If I'm able to get anything to work, it just ends up putting "EventGuest" in the cell due to getGuestList() returning an array.

This is our companies one and only Google Apps Script task to assist with reporting so we haven't written anything like this before. Hoping for any assistance!

Comment: ]getGuestlist returns an array of EventGuests](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest) Iterate through all of the events and each array of eventGuests() and that should be it.

Comment: I believe that's what I'm stuck on. I made EventGuests a variable using guestArrayItem then tried to get the name out of it with guestDetails. I may need to explicitly state it in my main post, but events[i] should iterate through every event that fits my criteria. I think I'm mainly stuck on how I'm supposed to pull data from the resulting array, EventGuests.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this for each event.

```
function getGuests() {
  const cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  const ev = cal.getEventById("eventid");
  const list = ev.getGuestList();
  let guests = list.map(e => [e.getName(),e.getEmail()]);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Guests");
  guests.unshift(["Name","Email"]);
  sh.getRange(1,1,guests.length, guests[0].length).setValues(guests);
}
```

Comment: Could you give me some insight into this line?

 let guests = list.map(e => [e.getName(),e.getEmail()]); I feel like our code does almost the same thing but I'm unsure what exactly this line is doing. I have more code that I didn't show but it's nigh identical.

Comment: I just used the the array map method too return a 2 d array of two columns of data.  It uses arrow notation.